# Escaping characters in a command sent from a system to Unix

Tags: c, unix, character-encoding, escaping

How would you escape the following line from a C-based system to Unix command line so that this exact line is used by Unix:

```
tr "\304\305\326" "\134\135\136" </stx/users/n/tmp/tmpfile1.tmp>/stx/users/n/tmp/tmpfile2.tmp
```

The most obvious would be:

```
build("|tr \"\\304\\305\\326\" \"\\134\\135\\136\", "<", tmp1, ">", tmp2")
```

But when run, it gives a file not found error in Unix. When the extra  \" are removed, it writes the file OK, but the problem is the string replacement does not work. With the line above, the characters are replaced OK.

Apostrophes cannot be used for the octal characters, because then the system will pass them as actual characters, eg. **Ö** instead of **\326**

The function "build" is a function of the C-based system in use. Basically a string builder. The pipe is used to make the command run in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you build function should actually do, but also remember that you have to escape whitespace characters as well.